# Posix Semaphore as a Thread-Safe Counter

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need a thread-safe counter that won't block the thread. (For pre-C11 tools.) Locking a mutex around ++/-- operations can block it. So I came up with this, using semaphores. Is it sensible?

```
#include <semaphore.h>

class AtomicCounter {
public:
  AtomicCounter(unsigned int i=0) { sem_init(&m, 0, i); }
  ~AtomicCounter() { sem_destroy(&m); }

  operator unsigned int() { int a; sem_getvalue(&m, &a); return a; }
  AtomicCounter& operator++() { sem_post(&m); return *this; }
  AtomicCounter& operator--() { sem_trywait(&m); return *this; }

private:
  AtomicCounter(const AtomicCounter&);
  AtomicCounter& operator=(const AtomicCounter&);
  sem_t m;
};
```

**EDIT**
An alternative would need to support ARMv7 and x86 and work with any common compiler.

Comment: You know that atomic operations are built-in to 95% of processors, right? Just use some targeted inline assembly.

Comment: Is it acceptable for your counter to do _nothing_ when you tell it to decrement? trywait can fail. Other than that, it looks OK but it won't be super fast. Even without C11 you should be able to use atomic increments/decrements at the sacrifice of a little portability (but if you add 2 or 3 ifdefs, you can cover pretty much every important architecture).

Comment: It would be lovely to find a multi-platform library with support for most cpu types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regularly use an adaptation of the method described by [Golubenco & Sarbu](http://golubenco.org/2007/06/14/atomic-operations/) to solve this problem.

This works with gcc; I have only tried this on x84 and amd64 architectures.

Essentially, you declare some counter macros, or inline functions if C++, that use the compiler provided intrinsic functions for safe multi-thread / multi-core increment, decrement and test.

It doesn't quite have pure C++ semantics, which is OK in my use case because I have code shared between C and C++, but it wouldn't be a lot of effort to incorporate into your class.